# Apartments in Jakarta, Indonesia

Tags: accommodation, indonesia, jakarta

I am planning to spend 3-4 months in Jakarta, with my little family (wife and kid) I don't want to stay in a hotel for this long, I heard there are nice apartments with reasonable prices in Jakarta (2 rooms, Toilet and kitchen) for monthly rent. Any suggestions on where to find that?

Comment: Could you give any budget and which area do you want to stay? (Central/South/West/East Jakarta) You can give any specific location since I live in Jakarta for more than 6 years.

Comment: Too be honest, in the order to rent an apartment,  foreigner should pay at least 1000-1500 USD per month.

Comment: Agree with Rudy here, that budget is unrealistic: you're not going to get anything even halfway decent in a good part of town for $500/mo.  Can I ask what you will be doing in Jakarta for 3-4 mo?  It's not exactly a tourist destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your budget, it's quite difficult to rent a service Apartment.

The only way to go is to rent the apartment from the owner directly. You can try [Roomorama](https://roomorama.com/short-term-rentals?utf8=%C3%A2%C2%9C%C2%93&order=&check_in=Check%20in&check_out=Check%20out&guests=1&destination=jakarta&number_of_rooms=&min_price=15&max_price=51&d%5B%5D=&d%5B%5D=2532&d%5B%5D=2533&d%5B%5D=2534&d%5B%5D=2535&d%5B%5D=2536&t%5B%5D=apartment) or [AirBnb](http://www.airbnb.com/search?location=jakarta&price_min=10&price_max=55&room_types%5B%5D=Entire%20home/apt) for this. If you click on the Rates tab, both website also provide monthly rent rates. Personally I think you may get a better luck with Roomorama.

However you may want to top up a little since the one I saw have rate around 600-700 USD/month.

Comment: Thanks Rudy, I decided 400-500 USD because I have seen an apartment, 2 rooms and a toilet and kitchen which costed an indonesian friend around 350 USD and it is in petukangan area. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 3):

3-4 months is too short for most rental agencies, which means your best option is probably going to be a service apartment.  Plenty of choices (Ascott, Oakwood, Somerset etc), just Google around.

The first and most important question is, where will you be spending your days in Jakarta?  The traffic is astonishingly terrible and you want to stay as close to your place of work as possible.  Many expats favor the Kuningan area, which has plenty of modern accommodation and is close to the main business districts.